# how to use sizzle.js separate

Tags: javascript, sizzle

I downloaded sizzle.js from https://github.com/jquery/sizzle
my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="sizzle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=load;
        function load(){
            alert(Sizzle("#test"));
            alert(Sizzle("#test").innerHTML);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">abc</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but alert "[object]", "undefined", please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Sizzle()` function returns an *array* of matched elements. So if you know there'll be exactly one matching element (which there should be if you're selecting by id) try:

```
alert(Sizzle("#test")[0].innerHTML);
```

Comment: thanks,but why select by id returns an array? in jquery select by id is a single emelemt.

Comment: No, in jQuery `$("#test")` returns an array too (well, an array-like object). It's just that in jQuery when you use jQuery methods on the result like `$("#test").html()` the jQuery methods know they're dealing with an array, they don't give an error if nothing matched, and for methods that return a value (like `.html()`) if more than one element matched they just return the value from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You've did a slight mistake it returns [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) not a single [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node).
The [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) is like an array but used for storing [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)s. You may probably want to use the first one.

```js
// this is how you do it
alert( Sizzle('#test')[0].innerHTML );
```